# How can I add a second developer to a File Action in Box?

Tags: box-api

When I create a new App in Box with a file action, it automatically gets added to my box account and I have access to the file actions when I right-click on a file. I need another developer to have access to the same file action so we can develop and test it before we ask to put it live.

In the "Edit a Box Application" page I can add developers so that they can edit the application. I type their name into the box and save it, then they are able to get into the same screen and edit the details of the application. The problem is that when they right click on a file the file action is not presented as an option. When we look at the list of apps on their Box account our app in development is not there, which explains why they cannot see the file action.

How do we add our application to their account so that they can see the file action without having to set the application as publicly available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have to install the application onto their Box account.  Have them go to https://cloud.app.box.com/services/ and they should be able to click the "+ Add" button to add the app to their Box account.   That will let them have the UI components show up in their Box account.

Go to https:developers.box.com --> Click "My Box Apps" --> click "name of your app" --> copy the url from the browser--> tell your buddy to navigate to that URL.

Comment: But how do they find the application when I haven't made it public? When they search for it by name they don't have any results, so can't click any "+ Add" buttons.

Comment: You'll have to send them the full URL to get to the application.  Use your own account and navigate to the "My Applications" then click the name of the application.   That URL will be available to your other developer users.

Comment: Thanks for your help but that doesn't really solve my problem. I need to develop and test for the situation where a second person from Box interacts with the file. The important thing is that they have their own Box userId and auth_token, etc. I can already test this in a fake way, but to do an integration test where I can say that everything is okay I need to understand the behavior when a real second user interacts with it.

Comment: Add them as a developer on your application using a different email address than yours, then have them add the application to their Box account.  You'll be able to test out the full flow of your application with multiple users.

Comment: But that is the question I'm asking - how can they add the app to their box account when its not publicly available? I have added them as a developer but it still doesn't show as something they can add.

Comment: Go to https:developers.box.com --> Click "My Box Apps" --> click "name of your app" --> copy the url from the browser--> tell your buddy to navigate to that URL.

Comment: Ah-ha, now I see what you mean. Thanks for your help. So in summary, you need to click on the name of the app and not the "edit" button. This will give you a URL that you can share with the other developer(s).